# How can I receipt users?

Tags: c#, class, object, get

We are two classes :

**First class is:**

```
public class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        UsersMyTeam = new List<User>();
        ID = "";
    }
    public string ID { set; get; }
    public string NameTeam { set; get; }

    public List<User> UsersMyTeam { set; get; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Team";
    }
}
```

Second class is :

```
public class User
{       
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string TeamID { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "User";
    }       
}
```

**I use of class by code:**

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
     DALTableIO DTIO = new DALTableIO();
     List<Team> listUser = new List<Team>();
     Team myTeam = new Team();
     myTeam.ID = "426f63a7-7f42-485f-8407-67c680f9e358";
     foreach (object item in DTIO.GetAll(myTeam))
     {
         listUser.Add((Team)item);
     }
}
```

I have a **class named `DALTableIO`** that get values from database and Put them into object of class:

```
public class DALTableIO:DALBase
{
    public List<object> GetAll(object MyClass)
    {
        SqlDataReader re = ExecuteReader(CommandType.StoredProcedure, string.Concat("GetAll", MyClass.ToString()), new SqlParameter[]{
            });
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        try
        {
            while (re.Read())
            {
                Type t=MyClass.GetType();
                // creat new Class
                object item = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                // start Fill Class
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in MyClass.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    //when we have property of list<object>
                    if (property.PropertyType.Name.ToLower() == "list`1")
                    {
                        //how can i create list<users> 
                        //how can i create user
                        //how can i do list<users> =getAll(user);
                        //how can i do property=list<users>;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (property.PropertyType.Name.Substring(0, 3) == "Int")
                        item.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(item, int.Parse(re[property.Name].ToString()));
                    else
                        switch (property.PropertyType.Name)
                        {
                            case "String":
                                item.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(item, re[property.Name].ToString());
                                break;
                            case "Decimal":
                                item.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(item, decimal.Parse(re[property.Name].ToString()));
                                break;
                        }
                }
                list.Add(item);
            }
            if (!re.IsClosed)
                re.Close();
            re.Dispose();
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw new Exception( err.Message);
        }

    }
```

Tell me how can I fill users `list<>`. I want send one class user to `getAll()` for give all users. thanks.

Comment: why arg of GetAll(object MyClass) is object?

Comment: Because i wand send different class .

Comment: Do you want to initialize the `List<User>` and add items?

Comment: yes.i want to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, it may help you.

```
if (property.PropertyType.Name.ToLower() == "list`1")
{
     if (property.PropertyType.Name.ToLower() == "list`1")
     {
          var type = property.PropertyType;
          var it = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

          var users = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // list of user
          var user = Activator.CreateInstance(it);    //user

          user.GetType().GetProperty("ID").SetValue(user, 1, null);
          user.GetType().GetProperty("Name").SetValue(user, "Name1", null);

          var add = type.GetMethod("Add");
          add.Invoke(users, new[] { user });
     }
}
```

Comment: I can't access User class in DALTableIO class.I send Team class to DALTableIO class.team class have property of list<User>.

Comment: I know only property is list<class>

Comment: X-TECH! Very grateful.you are my hero!!

Comment: Ok , Thank you again.